# Give an upper bound to the derivative of a complex function in terms of $\sup_{z,w \in D} {|f(z)-f(w)|}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let f be an analytic complex function in $D=B(0,1)$, and let 
>   $d=\sup_{z,w \in D} {|f(z)-f(w)|}$.
>
> Prove that: $|f'(0)| \le \frac{d} {2}$

My attempt: choose any ${w}_{0} \in D$ and $ 0<R<1$, then by Cauchy's integral formula:

$$\begin{split} |f'(0)|&=\frac { 1 }{ 2\pi  } \left|\int _{ |w|=R }{ \frac { f(w) }{ { w }^{ 2 } } dw } \right|=\frac { 1 }{ 2\pi  } \left|\int _{ |w|=R }{ \frac { f(w)-f({ w }_{ 0 }) }{ { w }^{ 2 } } dw } \right| \\ 
& \le \frac { 1 }{ 2\pi  } \cdot 2\pi R\cdot \frac { 1 }{ { R }^{ 2 } } \cdot \sup_{ |w|=R }|f(w)-f({ w }_{ 0 })|  
 \le \frac { d }{ R } 
\end{split}$$

Choose $R=1- \frac{1}{n}$ and let $n \rightarrow \infty$, so you'd get  $|f'(0)| \le d$.

Is there any way to improve this result and get the needed one?

Answer (score 2):

The function $g(z) = \frac12 (f(z)-f(-z))$ has the same derivative at $0$, and satisfies $|g(z)|\le d/2$. The Schwarz lemma finishes the story.

(You could also also follow your original proof with $g$ in place of $f$. But notice that you are just reproving the Schwarz lemma.)

---

The above is a special case of a common trick in complex variables: forming sums such as 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\zeta^k z)
$$
or 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{-mk} f(\zeta^k z)
$$
to isolate only certain Taylor coefficients  of $f$.